# I was dismissed from my university. Do I need a new F1 visa?

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa

I am a foreign citizen and was studying in the US. I was dismissed from my university in June 2017. My SEVIS record was terminated in October for a failure to enrol in new classes.

I have now been accepted into another college in the US. I have obtained a new I20 from this school. The program begins in February 2018. I am currently in my home country. Do I need a new F1 visa to study at the new university? Note that the I20 I have been issued is a new initial attendance I20 and not a transfer I20. Of course, when I re-enter, my visa will have a different university name on it than my I20.

Thank you.

Comment: I am a foreign citizen and was studying in the US. I was dismissed from my university in fall 2022. My SEVIS record will be terminated soon due to failure to enrol in new classes. If I apply to other universities in fall 2023 in the US and obtain a new I20 from this school, the program begins in September 2023. I am currently in my home country. Do I need a new F1 visa to study at the new university? Note that the I20 I have been issued is a new initial attendance I20 and not a transfer I20. Of course, when I re-enter, my visa will have a different university name on it than my I20. Do I have

Answer (score 1):

Your status is not determined by what visa you have, but once you travel abroad, you will need to obtain a new visa from the US embassy/consulate there. Bring all the relevant paperwork for this, and be prepared to explain your situation

Comment: So basically if I travel outside the US while not in status, I _will_ need to get a new visa?

Comment: @user71611 Yes, either if your visa expired or is otherwise no longer valid. **However**, if you're in the middle of the process of transferring, I **strongly** recommend you not to leave the country, and if it's about a death in your family, contact the USCIS and your new University about it

Comment: My visa is valid (expiry date) till 2020. Do I still need a new F1 visa?  What do you mean by "otherwise no longer valid"? I have already left the country I'm afraid (I had to due to lack of status). Thank you.

Comment: @user71611 Well your visa has to be issued on the basis of the university stated on your current I-20, otherwise it's invalid

Comment: "Well your visa has to be issued on the basis of the university stated on your current I-20, otherwise it's invalid" Not true. F1 students who transfer to a new school in the US under the same SEVIS number can still later leave and enter on the existing F1 visa.

Comment: @user102008 This Person had their SEVIS record terminated. AFAIK that'll mean a new SEVIS number (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Coke you're not wrong; OP was dismissed by the university and, as a consequence, was out of status and, thus, does not have an existing F-1. Given the academic dismissal, OP must again apply for the visa.

Comment: @Giorgio if the student was outside the US at the time of dismissal, the student was never out of status.

Answer (score -1):

There are several reasons why you should get a new visa in this case. Note also that you may face a higher bar than usual in convincing the officer that you're eligible for the visa, so you should be ready to explain your situation.

- First, since you're getting a new SEVIS ID and not applying for [reinstatement](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/FR/HTML/FR/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-79324/0-0-0-85465/0-0-0-87514/0-0-0-87971.html), you won't have a way to regain valid status within the US.
- Second, if you were out of status in the US, your old visa is automatically invalid per [INA 222(g)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1202). Furthermore, you must apply for the new visa at the US consulate in your country of nationality except in extraordinary circumstances.
- Finally, even if you left the US before any status violation, simply because your new I-20 has a new SEVIS ID, you generally should get a new F-1 visa.

Comment: "if you were out of status in the US, your old visa is automatically invalid per INA 222(g)": 222(g) only applies if there is a formal finding of status violation.