# Do i have to renew my visa?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, student-visa, study

I am a foreign citizen and was studying in the US. I was dismissed from my university in fall 2022. My SEVIS record will be terminated soon due to failure to enrol in new classes.

If I apply to other universities in fall 2023 in the US and obtain a new I20 from this school, the program begins in September 2023. I am currently in my home country. Do I need a new F1 visa to study at the new university? Note that the I20 I have been issued is a new initial attendance I20 and not a transfer I20. Of course, when I re-enter, my visa will have a different university name on it than my I20.

Do I have to renew my student visa? It is valid till 2025.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was dismissed from my university. Do I need a new F1 visa?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12759/i-was-dismissed-from-my-university-do-i-need-a-new-f1-visa)

Comment: @phoog: This question seems mostly copy-pasted from that question

Comment: @user102008 indeed, which is why I decided to vote to close as a duplicate.  Perhaps I should have changed the auto-comment to the old wording, "possible duplicate of..." or even just to "duplicate of."

Comment: @user102008 indeed, which is why I decided to vote to close as a duplicate.  Perhaps I should have changed the auto-comment to the old wording, "possible duplicate of..." or even just to "duplicate of."